# Über den Indefinitartikel "all-" im Genitiv

Tags: grammar

Ich lerne Deutsch, und ich verstehe nicht, warum der Indefinitartikel "**all**-" im singularen maskulinen und neutralen Genitiv **all**-*es*  oder "**all**-*en*" sein kann?

Ich verstehe nicht, wann ich "**all**-*es*" benutzen kann, und wann ich "**all**-*en*" benutzen kann?

Comment: @Ingmar, ich habe nicht verstanden, warum "wenn" nicht korrekt ist? Habe ich keinen Konditionalsatz in diesem Fall?

Comment: It's slightly more complicated, but basically _wann = when_ and _wenn = if_. In this case, anyway, _wann_ is correct.

Comment: @mle... you can see it as a conditional clause but that's not the point. It's "wann" because it is an indirect question - never mind whether it's temporal or conditional. These two are hard to tell apart anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gute Frage. Ich wusste es auch nicht:

Laut [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Besonderheiten/Genitiv-es-en.html) gilt für *alles* die folgende Regel:

> Einige Pronomen, die im Genitiv Singular Maskulin und Neutrum die Endung **es** haben, können vor männlichen und sächlichen Nomen wie ein Adjektiv mit der Endung **en** stehen. Dies geschieht nur, wenn das Nomen den Genitiv mit der Endung **s** oder **es** bildet. 
>   In allen anderen Stellungen verwendet man für den Genitiv Maskulin und Neutrum die Pronomenform mit der Endung **es**.

Beispiele:

> - [Wurzel allen Übels](https://www.textlog.de/17909.html)
> - die Grundlage allen geistigen Lebens

Den Genitiv von *Übel* und *Leben* bildet man mit *s*. Wohingegen:

> - ein Bewunderer alles Schönen

Comment: in primis danke, aber ich verstehe nicht, es tut mir leid. Der singulare maskuline und neutrale Genitv von einem Substantiv ist immer mit s/es-Endung...denke ich gut?

Comment: @mle Eben weil das nicht der Fall ist: nicht alle mask. und neutr. Nomen bilden den Genitiv mit Endung *s* oder *es*. Das dritte Beispiel zeigt eine Aushahme. Eine zweite "Der Rüssel alles Elefanten ist ..."

Comment: Ed gibt kein Adjektiv „elefant“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz ... ich habe nie solches Nomen als Adjektiv betrachtet. Ist der Satz falsch? Oder die Erklärung vielleicht? Ich kann auch ein nicht erfundenes Beispiel anbieten: *Man wird zum Beispiel sehen, dass die Eigenwerte jedes Graphen...*

Comment: Genau, „jedes“. Oder „aller Graphen“, nicht „alles Graphen“. Frag mich nicht nach Regeln... Gäbe es ein Adjektiv „elefant“, so könnte man es für das Adjektiv „schön“ in Deinem Beispiel einsetzen, darauf wollte ich hinaus, aber es war wohl nicht so witzig wie gehofft. Der Nominativ ist übrigens „alles Schöne“, und „alles“ wird für Unzählbares benutzt, Elefanten kann man zählen, also wäre der Nominativ „alle Elefanten“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ach so, jetzt verstehe ich.